# is it possible to extract substrings from schema 1.1 attributes with xpath/regex? if so, how?

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, xsd, schema

i have been looking for hours (schema/xpath newbie) into how one could extract substrings from xsd attributes. what i essentially wish to do is to keyref said attribute substrings, like so:

```
<param name="public_images" type="boolean" value_source="account_settings.public_images"/>
```

here, i wish to extract 'account_settings' and 'public_images' by splitting by the '.' character, via any means possible, the value of @value_source, and then key each "token" from ( "account_settings", "public_images" ) to some other attribute/element in the schema (which i know how to do, so this part needs no explanation).

similarly, i wish to reference the following 'SOME_VALUE' values from {SOME_VALUE} patterns below with a key attribute/element in the code:

```
<value>Client-ID {client_id}</value>
<access_header name="Authorization" value="Client-ID {client_id}"/>
```

is there any way to accomplish this by using the pattern/selector/field schema tools, xpath/regex or otherwise? please note this should all be within the contents of a schema 1.1 file with the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema namespace.

please help, this is a very time-sensitive issue, and any advice/help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks sincerely, 
Piotr.

Comment: If you don't care about structure and just want to extract certain strings without outer context then regexp is easiest way.

Comment: @Andrey, thank you very much for the response! :) would you be able to provide an example, how i could do this (preferably referencing the examples i have provided in my question)? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe lies outside the capabilities of XSD 1.0 or 1.1 key/keyref constraints:  they can check that a given value which occurs in the document as a keyref also occurs in the document as a key, but functions like substring-before and substring-after are not available in XSD identity constraints.

If the value_source attribute were split into two attributes, you'd have no particular problem using identity constraints to solve your problem.  Given the XML structure you've got, however, if you're in XSD 1.1 your only realistic option is to use assertions to impose the constraints you have in mind.

[Addition] You don't say where document keeps the key values to which the parts of the value_source attribute value must correspond, so a complete working example will necessarily be a bit of a work of fiction.  But let us assume that `param` elements can occur anywhere in the document, and the individual dot-delimited parts of their @source_value attribute must match the @id value on a `source` element occurring as a child of `value_sources`, which in turn occurs as a child of `other-stuff`, which it itself a child of the root element.

In the declaration of the complex type used on the root element, then, you'd add an assertion of something like the following form:

```
<xs:assert test="
    every $param in .//param
    satisfies 
    (every $sourceref in tokenize($param/@value_source,'\.')
    satisfies 
    (some $sourcedecl in ./other-stuff/value_sources/source
    satisfies 
    ($sourcedecl/@id = $sourceref)))
    " />
```

The key point to remember is that XSD 1.1 assertions can only point downward, into the element whose type contains the assertions.  So you can't put the assertion on the `param` element.  You have to put it on some element which is guaranteed to contain both the `param` element and the elements or attributes whose values the `param/@value_source` is constrained to match.  If, as you say, you know how to write the key constraints for the case where the value_source doesn't have to be tokenized, then you should have no problem figuring out how to point to the relevant values here.

Note, however, that XSD 1.1 implementations are not required to support all of XPath 2.0 in assertions; they are allowed to support only a smaller subset of XPath.  Saxon and Xerces, however, both seem to handle the assertion given above without trouble.

Comment: M. Sperberg-McQueer, thanks! would assertions however be able to test whether, say element $1 and element $2 of "account_settings.public_images" split by '.' correspond to key attribute/element values in the schema? if so, how would one go about this? :)

Comment: Piotr, yes; you'll want to read up on XSD 1.1 assertions and on the quantified expressions of XPath 2.0.  See the example I've just added to the answer.

Comment: thanks so much! i will test it out as soon as i get something to eat, but yes, i am using xerces and xsd 1.1, so it should work! ;) i assume that the same can be applied to <access_header name="Authorization" value="Client-ID {client_id}"/> with something along the lines of "in (.*)\{(.*)\}(.*)"? how would that be possible?

Comment: In principle, you have the complete XPath function library to use in parsing out the parts of the values that need to match (but see note about XSD 1.1 conformance not requiring all of XPath).  I won't try to work out the Client-ID example in detail because I don't understand it, but by all means look at the [XPath Functions and Operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) spec under [String functions that use pattern matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match).